# Do JPA 2.1's Entity Graphs carry out/make redundant the functionality of EclipseLink's Fetch/Load Groups?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

EclipseLink has extension functionality, namely [fetch and load groups](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/AttributeGroup) which allow finer control over the fetching and loading of data from a datastore in comparison to the standard JPA 2.0 capabilities.

Now, in JPA 2.1, [entity graphs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.5/JPA21#Entity_Graphs) seem to provide similar functionality.

Do entity graphs effectively make EclipseLink's fetch and load group extensions redundant in JPA 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding was that Entity graphs are the JPA's way of exposing EclipseLink's attribute groups.  The native attribute groups can expose more of the underlying functionality.

Comment: Do you have any source or reference for this info?